Artifact download is progressing very slowly in ecplice ide
I'm encountering significant delays and intermittent freezing during the installation of Eclipse. I'm receiving messages indicating slow progress in artifact download and the installation process taking longer than usual. This is occurring despite having fast internet speed, so that's not the potential cause of the issue. I'm seeking assistance in understanding the reasons behind this delay and how to address it effectively.
I uninstalled Eclipse and attempted to reinstall it, but the installation process is still not working as expected.

Are you talking about the Eclipse Installer? You can also download IDE packages.

Try downloading from a different mirror.
